# phone stolen and locked but recovered

Tags: security

My wife's android phone was stolen so she locked it remotely. About a week later we were able to make contact with the thief and he returned it for a small reward.

How do we unlock it?

Comment: "she locked it remotely" - how? through Android Device Manager, Airwatch, or some other software?

Answer (score 0):

After turning the phone on, you will be prompted to enter a password. If prior to the theft, you had the phone locked with a code, you should be able to enter that code to get in.

If your phone had no lock prior to the disappearance, you will have to enter the code that you chose when locking using *Google find my device*.

As you can see in the screenshot, being that this phone doesn't have a code lock, it asks me to choose one when locking. Does this screen seem familiar?
[image]